# AngularJS : TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller inside which I have two toggle buttons to display the view accordingly. The two types of view that are shown in the controller are controlled by the `$scope.isStore` variable which is the deciding factor in the `html` part.

But once I toggle the part that is supposed to be changed becomes blank and I get the following error.

```
angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:9017)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8333)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8336)
at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:8336)
at publicLinkFn (angular.js:8213)
at lazyCompilation (angular.js:8551)
at boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:8350)
at controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:9072)
at ngIfWatchAction (angular.js:25323)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16869)
```

I tried looking for solutions but none worked for me. Even when setting a `setTimeout` function when changing the $scope variable gives the same output.

HTML Part :

```
        <div id="go-pro" class="storeCoins" ng-if="isPremiumUser==true">
            <span class="coinText">you are Premium User</span>
            <img class="imgPro"  id="feature" ng-src="/app/app_resources/icons/pirate_girl.png" />
        </div>


            <table id="links" class="tab-selector">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tablinks" ng-class="{highlighwallet: isStore==true}" ng-click="walletController.showStore(event)">STORE</td>
                    <td class="tablinks" ng-class="{highlighwallet: isStore==false}" ng-click="walletController.showHistory(event)">TASK HISTORY</td>
                </tr>
            </table>



            <div ng-if="isStore==false">
                <ul>
                    <li class="taskList" ng-click="arbit()">
                        <div class="taskHistoryList" ng-repeat="taskList in mergedTransaction | orderBy:'-Date'">
                            <img  class="taskListImage" ng-src="{{walletController.getImage(taskList)}}">
                            <span ng-show="isCoinBought">{{ taskList.coin_value}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <div ng-if="isStore==true">
                <packgroup-directive>
                </packgroup-directive>
                 <div ng-controller="WalletController">
                   <outfit-directive></outfit-directive>
                 </div>
                   <h3>GO PRO</h3>
                <div id="go-pro" ng-if="isPremiumUser==false">
                    <img class="feature" ng-click="walletController.onGoPremiumChosen()" id="feature" ng-src="/app/app_resources/language/en/resources/banner.jpg" />

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

JS Part :

```
walletModel.showStore = function () {
        console.log("ShowStore")
          $scope.isStore = true;
          $scope.$apply();
    }
```

Full Controller JS : https://justpaste.it/1dqxh

JS for the directive : https://justpaste.it/1dqxj

Comment: issue is in your controller where you trying to access childNodes. Js part provided is not enough to detect the exact issue. please provide some more information.

Comment: @sumitchauhan Should I provide the full JS part, of the controller as well as the directive that's being used?

Comment: Please if you can.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined` ... it probably crashes for you due to an invalid identifier

Comment: @sumitchauhan shared.

Comment: Do you know difference between 'ng-if' and 'ng-show'? 'ng-if' do not create element when its value is false, and 'ng-show' active just like 'hidden'. So to fix your problem, I think, you should have to change 'ng-if' to 'ng-show' or control this in '.js'

Comment: @CanetRobern I've spent the last 24 hours digging through StackOverflow for this answer. Can you please submit this as the answer so I can upvote it again?

Comment: @Xenology Oh Did this fix your problem?? :D I'm happy to hear that! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know difference between `ng-if` and `ng-show`?

`ng-if` do not create element when its value is false,

and `ng-show` active just like `hidden`.

So to fix your problem, I think, you should have to change `ng-if` to `ng-show` or control this in '.js'